# Jest expected actions test fails

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux

I have the following test:

```
it('should handle searchForRepairs', async () => {

  await store.dispatch((searchForRepairs as any)(''))

  const state = {
    repairs: store.getActions().reduce(reducer, initialState)
  }

  expect(getRepairsProperty(state)).toMatchObject( 
    [{
      id: '',
      jobNo: '',
      trade: '',
      priority: '',
      status: '',
      raisedDate: '',
      appointmentDate: '',
      completedDate: '',
      description: '',
    }]
  )

  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual({})
})
```

where the first expect passes but no the second where I get the following:

[image]

the test would failt because I am checking it against an empty object but I would expect from `store.getActions()` to have the actions type included in `searchForReapirs` from `await store.dispatch((searchForRepairs as any)(''))`.

I would expect it to fail because `{type: 'SOME_TYPE'}` is different from `{}`, they are basically returning empty

`searchForRepairs` action:

```
export const searchForRepairs = (searchTerm: string) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => AppState
) => {
  if (!searchTerm) return

  dispatch({
    type: REPAIRS_SEARCH,
    // payload: { searchTerm },
  })

  const customerId = getCustomerId(getState())

  const propertyRepairs = await api.searchRepairs(`${customerId} AND ${searchTerm}`)

  dispatch({
    type: REPAIRS_SEARCH_SUCCESS,
    payload: propertyRepairs,
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, can you provide all the relevant source code for the test, please?

Comment: @mgarcia I have updated it with the code for the action being dispatched. Thanks